# Reducing non-determinism with Detours?

Tags: c, random, hook, detours, deterministic

I was wondering if it is possible to use hooking (like Detours) to remove non-determinism in an arbitrary application.

We can assume single-thread applications (to ignore non-determinism caused by races and scheduling).

My first guess was to override `rand()` in order to have predictable and repeatable output for any function asking for pseudo-random numbers, regardless of the seed.

Are there any other commonly used functions that I should consider overriding?

I know that there is no flawless solution here, but one that works for most applications will probably do.
Also if there is another way to solve this problem, I will be interesting in reading about it.

Comment: *Please* don't use Detours. The only non-determinism it will remove is whether the app will crash or not (it will). EasyHook is a much, much more stable alternative and a bit more functional (though poorly documented).

Comment: Don't forget bugs such as using uninitialized variables/memory (on the stack or in the heap). You probably won't catch them.

Comment: Is it that bad? EasyHook seems to be abandoned since 2009, while Detours 3 was released this year. Were your bad experiences with that one or the older versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to actually remove `rand()` and friends because they are pseudo-random-number generators. For the same seed, rand() will yield the same results, so what you actually need to catch is the call to `time()` that is used to initialize the RNG.

The key insight is that non-deterministic effects happen mostly due to scheduling (which has no influence for a large part of the single-threaded applications), the result of system calls and non-initialized memory in the program. You need to control the results of system calls to control the input of your program. `strace` is a very good tool for determining which function calls need overriding. To check if any memory is used uninitialized, use `valgrind`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.